# Get parameters from Actions On Google's List in DialogFlow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to get a parameter from actions on google's list in dialogflow. (Without using a Webhook) Is that possible? I created some intents to test and that's not working at all, neither the input nor the vocal choise. The parameter received is always null. 
Here's my test intent:

Intent Structure
[image: Intent Structure]

Prova List's Object 1
[image: Prova List's Object 1]

Prova - custom Events and Phrases
[image: Prova - custom Events and Phrases]

Prova - custom Response
[image: Prova - custom Response]

Actions on Google simulator
[image: Actions on Google simulator]

Without the value $num everithing works properly...

Comment: There's an Actions on Google sample available on Github specifically featuring all the possible responses [here](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-conversation-components-nodejs)